# Update multiple documents in MongoDB by field's current value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an Employees Schema :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const EmployeesSchema = new Schema({

  EmployeeId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },


  // .... more attributes


  Copies: {
    type: Number,
    required: true

  InsertDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Employees = mongoose.model(
  "employees",
  EmployeesSchema
);
```

and ids array ...

```
const _ids = // I get this one from some code manipulation - return the `_id` attribute
```

and I want to update those documents that are in `_ids` , by one attribute - `Copies` :

```
await Employees.update(
    {
      _id: {
        $in: _ids
      }
    },
    {
      $set: { Copies: Copies - 1 }  // here it looks for a var called Copies
    },
    { multi: true }
  );
```

How can I reduce `1` from `Copies` attribute , based on each document's `Copies` value ?

Comment: Your schema says Copies is a string, do you mean it to be of type Number?

Comment: @user753642: My bad , fixed.thanks